# object x parented to Armature bone, object y parented to object x, Y doesn't move when i move the bone

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints, parent

[enter link description here](http://[%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1498%22%20/%3E](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1498/))[image]

so object x has the parent armature and weight painted to "bone", all the "y" objects are parented to Object x, when i move object x the y's move along with it just fine, but when i move Bone the Y objects dont move along and just stay there.
What do i do?

Comment: Could you share an extract of your blend file so that we could see how you did it ? To share a file, you can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1498" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1498/) @lemon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you likely parented Object 'X' to the Armature at the Object level, not at the bone level, which I suspect you intended.  Parent things to the bone level instead, as shown:
[image]

That all said, while this technically works, I strongly suggest just skinning everything, with no geometry-object parenting (except to get the entire mesh parented for proxies).  It makes depsgraph evaluation way easier, and it'll be easier to update in case you change your mind on the model after you begin animating.

Here's the result of your desired behavior (I haven't gotten rid of those constraints on the feathers, though).
[image]

Comment: I agree with your remark, Mike. In case you change your mind about it @pranavjitvirdi, the blend file of my answer is in this idea.

Comment: @lemon k will keep it in mind.

Comment: @lemon Oh perfect haha.  I just posted my answer seconds before you did, and I didn't notice yours.  Otherwise I would've just up-voted yours :P  Birds of a feather flock together, no pun intended.

Comment: Yes and not... in fact, effectively, the effect @pranavjitvirdi wants to have is more hard (or long) to obtain in the "conventional" way... so from that point of you, I cant disagree with pranavjitvirdi. (but of course no problem about your posts !)

Comment: pranavjivirdi Glad I could help!  But FYI lemon's take is cleaner, and makes it easier to revise.  Shallower object-level hierarchies are almost always better. @lemon: I'm not even sure what the "conventional" way is, you mean the use of skinning?

Comment: (well this is not a forum... some may say)... but yes skinning. But achieving the fan effect (like in @pranavjitvirdi original parenting) is hard to skin (from my experience) or needs to have a bone per feather (probably)

Comment: exactly, im new to rigging and most of the tutorials on this had the method of doing one bone per feather and then using drivers and data paths all of a sudden it got too overwhelming, it wasn't until a maya tutorial i came to know you could use constraints to achieve the fan out effect. and then i dodn't know about this levels of parenting so it was like a sudden brickwall for me. Thank god the solution was easy.

Comment: @pranavjitvirdi : who know what ? "how to rig a fan ?" can be an interesting question : ) ... answered here, it seems (did not checked the blend file for now) http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?237979-Never-seen-elsewhere-animating-a-japanese-fan (edit : well this link is only the base approach...)

Comment: @lemon : checked out the file, indeed an interesting setup, i never knew rigging required so much brainpower, but i guess once you're clear with how everything works it comes off easy.

Comment: @pranavjitvirdi I will try to study it a bit... or find another (I guess simple) solution... If it does not work, surely I will post the question in BSE (and keeping in mind that birds wings and japanese fans are not exactly the same problem) (I wont chat more here : this is not a forum...)

Comment: @pranavjitvirdi rigging is part art part science.  There's more than one good way of rigging this bird.  I remember doing a similar project in Maya for a college project.  I started with drivers too.  But in the end, a bunch of bones that I could rotate independently (even though it took longer) seemed to be the best method.  But that's just my experience. Slightly off-topic: this is why I want to get Animation Nodes working within Pose-mode -- allow for an easier, customizable driver system.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is "normal".

Y feathers are parented at the object level. But the object level stays in place when the X mesh (think about it as 'edit level') is moved by the bone.
Because the bone does not moves the center point of the wing.

What you can do it parenting your feathers like you did for the X wing.

Or set all wings and feathers in one object and parent it to the bones. Like this : [image]

Comment: but that doesn't accomplish what i wanted to do. in my original file rotate the object x and you'll see that the feathers all have constraints so that they condense together when rotated one side and spread out when rotated the other, if i directly parent then that effect wont work. :(

Comment: @pranavjitvirdi yes, I understand. So the other answer from Mike is the good one !